# Will signing in to iMessage on another device send an email to the Apple ID notifying of this?

Tags: apple-id, messages

I was told I could monitor my 13 year old daughter's messages on an old iPhone through Wi-Fi. I was told to set up message on the phone with her Apple ID and password.

My question is will Apple send her an email asking her to allow the messages to be sent to my phone? I know they send one telling her someone accessed her account. If they only send one saying someone signed into her account that's ok.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! I've substantially removed a lot of superfluous content from your question to distill it to its essence, but if you feel I've removed important information please edit the question to clarify the situation.

Comment: It is possible that if you have the monitoring device running with messages using the same id that in some cases where you have messages open they will be marked as read before your daughter sees them and may not even get an alert.

Comment: Not a answer to your question, but some Parenting experience sharing. I know she is only 13, but as a Parent I would tell her that I can see her messages. This is to keep trust and open communication, and to avoid been very surprised what you read. @Patrix feel free to delete this comment.

Comment: I know I should tell her I see her text but if I do she will just use a texting app a friends phone or somethin. Kids are smart they will find a way to do what they want.

Answer (score 3):

It will send an email telling her iMessage has been enabled on a device. But there's no grant/deny option, it's just an informational email.

Comment: Thank you very much! Can someone walk me through the process of setting up the old iPhone to recieve her messages? I know nothing about iphones

Comment: Go into settings, messages, enable iMessage and enter the AppleID